Is the Law of 1st Mention in hermenuetics based on where it is first mentioned in the Bible or chronologically?
For example: John 1:1 says, "In the beginning was the Word (Logos)..."  Even though this is the 4th gospel (Matt, Mark, Luke, John), it identifies the Logos as existing before the creation of the world, before time began.  Would it therefore be the first mention, not the first time logos is used in the New Testament; Matt. 5:37 "let your statement...."

Since there is dispute about the chronology of the books of scripture I can't see how this can work. And it isn't a 'law' anyway. (Just 'cos someone says it is.) Just out of interest it would be helpful if you actually stated what the law is. Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

This Biblical Hermeneutics question may shed light on what this Law of First Mention actually is: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/452/are-there-scriptural-warrants-for-using-the-rule-of-first-ment
